# findByIdAndRemove() returns no error if I pass the user id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making a RESTful API with CRUD functionalities powered by Node.js and MongoDB. I'm using mongoose. This is my function code:

```
// Create endpoint /api/characters/:character_id for DELETE
exports.deleteCharacter = function(req, res) {
  // Use the Character model to find a specific character and remove it
  Character.findByIdAndRemove({ userId: req.user._id, _id: req.params.character_id }, function(err) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);

    res.json({ message: 'Character removed from database!' });
  });
};
```

When I make a POST request to localhost:3000/api/characters/59bfa116f75cd610fc5a7549 (the parameter being the user id) I get the response of a correct removal (even though no character is actually removed), but the parameter passed should be the character's id, not the user's!

If I pass anything different from an existent user id I get an error response (correct behavior).

Comment: findByIdAndRemove takes a first argument ObjectId not a object. Also you should add return statement before res.send(err);

Comment: How do I put a condition to the remove?

Comment: You want [`.findOneAndRemove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove). Not found is not an error. But you can always test for the `null` result returned when there is no match

Comment: @Neil Lunn that was it! Testing for null